# Unable to uninstall Gephi software

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, uninstall

I have Ubuntu 16.04, I had installed Gephi 0.9.2, now when I try to uninstall, it says `E: Unable to locate package gephi`. I tried both the commands `sudo apt-get remove gephi` and `sudo apt-get remove gephi`. Earlier I was getting the error: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` so I ran the command `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`, and now I am getting the error: `E: Unable to locate package gephi`. But when I search for Gephi in the search bar of Ubuntu, I can see the Gephi icon but on clicking it doesn't open.

I tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get clean` too.

Can someone help me to clear Gephi from my system totally?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't really delete the lock file, unless you know what you are doing. When `apt-get` cannot get the lock, it means that another instance of this program is running and doing something! By removing this lock, you allow two instances to run at the same time and they both will modify the installed packages database, very likely in an inconsistent way. Instead you either need to wait for the first `apt-get` process to finish, or force its termination.

Comment: Wrt icon - some packages may create more files than they declare as installed, thus uninstalling them will leave some "garbage". You'll be probably OK to delete this icon / any other files this package left behind after uninstalling it.

Comment: I had tried waiting for apt-get to finish, I don't think any other process was using it. So I check it online and most suggestions was to remove the lock file. I have removed the folder that Gephi was using, still I am unable to locate how the icon is coming. Can you tell me where else I should check?

Comment: Well, in Linux, you have many ways to figure out what process(es) are locking the file, `lsof`, `lslk` will give you such info. From there you could figure whether the packages database is really being used, or the processes using the file are benign / already dead etc. Sometimes the process already finished using the file, but filesystem cache didn't refresh yet, so you need to wait a few seconds. If the icon is coming in search results--maybe it was cached by whatever handles the searches? If so, it will go away eventually, when this cache will be invalidated.